# How to update a webpage from a button click in a python webserver

Tags: python, button, webserver

I could not find an answer to this simple python question. How to change the content of a webpage from a button click using a simple python web server. Here is my stripped down code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer 
html = """<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     </head><body>Test<p><button>Update</button></body></html>"""

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(html, "utf-8"))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer(("192.168.1.197",1234), MyServer)
    print("Started")
    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found most of the answer at
https://tutorialedge.net/python/python-socket-io-tutorial/

But also see this about using sockets:
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/03/14/when-to-use-a-http-call-instead-of-a-websocket-or-http-2-0/

My test HTML:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="mydoc">Hello</p>
    <button onClick="sendMsg()">Update</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");
      function sendMsg() { socket.emit("message", "HELLO WORLD");}
      socket.on("message", function(data) { document.getElementById("mydoc").textContent = "There"; }); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would still like to know how to do this without sockets.